# SQL injection mid query

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I would like to improve my knowledge about the possible SQL injection attacks that exist. I know that parameterization completely avoids SQL injection risk and should therefore be applied everywhere. However, when someone asks me how it can be exploited, I like to have an answer.

I know how a basic SQL injection attack works. For example a website has a page `website.com/users/{id}` where id is the primary key of the user. If we trust the input completely and simply pass the id parameter to the query being executed, this can have dire consequences. In the case of `website.com/users/1` the query becomes `SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Id] = 1`. However, in the case of `website.com/users/1;DROP TABLE User` the query becomes `SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Id] = 1;DROP TABLE User`, leading to the nasty result.

But, pretty much all SQL injection attacks I read about count on the `WHERE` clause being present right before the injection. Almost always, the injection works in some form of `;Injected statement--`.

My question is, if it is also possible to perform a SQL injection attack given a query like the one below? Or in a broader sense: does the entire statement have to compile for a SQL injection attack to be possible, or will any error in the statement cause the attack to fail? If the answer is different per DBMS, please specify the DBMS.

In the query below, the injection is supposed to happen in the `CHARINDEX('input', [Name]) > 0` where `input` is copied from a user's input.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('input', [Name]) > 0
) AS [User]
LEFT JOIN
    [Setting] ON [Setting].[UserId] = [User].[Id]
```

The furthest I got myself was with the query below, but the error it returns, `Missing end comment mark '*/'`, seems to be completely blocking any attack.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('input', '') > 0) AS [User];DROP TABLE [NonExistentTable]/*, [Name]) > 0
) AS [User]
LEFT JOIN
    [Setting] ON [Setting].[UserId] = [User].[Id]
```

Comment: In your query, where does the string concatenation happen? That is where SQL is injected.

Comment: If you use parameters, then either it will choke before executing the query (`1;DROP..` is not an integer value), or just treat that "DROP" as part of the value, instead of a command

Comment: @SalmanA Let me see how I can make it more clear. But the part where injection is supposed to happen is CHARINDEX('input'.

Answer (score 3):

The resulting SQL has to be accepted by the particular DBMS for injection to occur, which generally means it needs to be valid SQL, but there are usually ways of crafting the input to make it valid regardless of the SQL in question.

If a line comment isn't enough, an extra statement can be added; if multiple statements aren't allowed, a `UNION` can be used; and so on.

The exact details vary, but with enough knowledge of the query (e.g. through error details leaking to the user) or lucky guesses, something can usually be crafted that is to the attacker's advantage.

In your example, consider this input, which simply repeats parts of the existing query:

```
nonsense', [Name]) > 0
    )
) AS [User];

Drop Table [User];

SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('nonsense
```

Which results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('nonsense', [Name]
    )
) AS [User];

Drop Table [User];

SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 10
        *
    FROM
        [User]
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('nonsense', [Name]) > 0
) AS [User]
LEFT JOIN
    [Setting] ON [Setting].[UserId] = [User].[Id]
```

Comment: Thanks! There is no simpler attack than repeating the query? Also, basically, if the query is executed via an API and it merely returns 400 in the case of a SQL error, an attacker will have to rely on luck?

Comment: @bdebaere It depends what you mean by "simpler" - it was the simplest thing for me to write, because I had full knowledge of the SQL. An attacker without full knowledge might well come up with something different, but the point is _injection is nearly always possible_, and that's really all you need to know. And yes, leaking less information in errors makes the attackers job harder, but they can still make informed guesses.

Comment: I'm not sure I will fully convince the person who wrote this if I tell him that, with knowledge of the query, you could construct a convoluted string fit for injection. So I was hoping there was a way without knowing the details of the entire query.

Comment: @bdebaere That sounds like an unwinnable argument: whatever example you come up with, they will come back with an "ah, but..." SQL Injection isn't an imaginary attack; real high-profile targets have been compromised using it. There is really no point your colleague wasting time examining every query for _how_ it can be attacked (or you wasting your time arguing with him) when the solution is always the same - separate your query and your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

SQL injection normally happens where some kind of string concatenation/insertion operation is involved. *It does not have to be the `WHERE` clause*. Also, generally speaking, the attacker is not interested in dropping the tables, he wants information. What if `input` is replaced by this:

```
', '') > 0 UNION ALL SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'password' --
```

Assuming that the result from select are displayed somehow and error messages are also shown, it'll take a few minutes for the attacker to determine the number and position of `, NULL` he should add before the query actually returns the name of table and column he wants to probe in the next stage.